Wildcards in android:host
i am trying custom domains in my android app , I intended to use android:host="*" and filter out the incoming deeplinks using android:pathpattern.
android:host = "*"
android:host = "*.com"
android:host = "*com"

the above hosts dont work , but consider if i have in coming link lie something.abc.com.au
android:host = "*.abc.com"
android:host = "*.com.au"

the above hosts matches the incoming links , but im forced to write the domain in the manifest
Is there any restriction that there must be some kind of test between the wildcard charater and the TLD?
I want to support multiple domains and subdomains which end with .com and without using mutliple intent filters or multiple hosts or explicity mentioning the subdomains.

Did you find any solution?
